Replicating logistic regression results from Stata in R
I'm facing an issue with replicating the results of a basic logistic regression model in R. The model was originally run in Stata.
The issue is that all of my odds ratios (and their underlying coefficients) are the same, except for one.
Stata code:
logistic sfcancer2yr c.age i.bminewcat i.n_rels i.race_eth i.meno i.bdnewcat i.biopsycoll i.birads i.bdnewcat#i.meno

R code:
trainmodel <- glm(sfcancer2yr ~ age + factor(bminewcat) + n_rels + factor(race_eth) + factor(meno) + bdnewcat + biopsycoll + birads + bdnewcat:meno, family = "binomial"(link = "logit"), data = traindata)

coef.orig <- coef(trainmodel)

exp(trainmodel$coefficients[-1])

When reviewing the results, it looks like only the OR for the variable "meno" is different.
Stata results:

Logistic regression                                     Number of obs = 68,605
                                                        LR chi2(13)   = 402.74
                                                        Prob > chi2   = 0.0000
Log likelihood = -6067.6077                             Pseudo R2     = 0.0321

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  sfcancer2yr | Odds ratio   Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          age |   1.025027   .0033988     7.45   0.000     1.018388    1.031711
              |
    bminewcat |
           2  |   1.383954    .095462     4.71   0.000     1.208948    1.584294
           3  |   1.385149   .1084733     4.16   0.000     1.188058    1.614937
              |
     1.n_rels |   1.580755    .111435     6.50   0.000     1.376763    1.814971
              |
     race_eth |
           2  |   .7453006   .1084842    -2.02   0.043     .5603155    .9913575
           3  |   .4592529    .087328    -4.09   0.000     .3163691    .6666683
           4  |   .8301742   .1199594    -1.29   0.198     .6254195    1.101963
           9  |   .7560139   .1817387    -1.16   0.245     .4719641    1.211018
              |
       1.meno |   1.680891    .253618     3.44   0.001     1.250569    2.259287
   2.bdnewcat |   2.710396   .3969418     6.81   0.000     2.034102    3.611541
 1.biopsycoll |   1.632317   .1289949     6.20   0.000     1.398099    1.905774
     2.birads |   1.469719   .0995559     5.68   0.000     1.286991     1.67839
              |
bdnewcat#meno |
         2 1  |   .5937504   .0942284    -3.28   0.001     .4350287    .8103821
              |
        _cons |     .00155   .0003223   -31.12   0.000     .0010312    .0023298
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: _cons estimates baseline odds.


R results
tidy(trainmodel, conf.int = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95, exponentiate = TRUE)

# A tibble: 14 × 7
   term               estimate std.error statistic   p.value conf.low conf.high
   <chr>                 <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 (Intercept)        0.000389   0.325      -24.2  3.29e-129 0.000203  0.000726
 2 age                1.03       0.00332      7.46 8.98e- 14 1.02      1.03    
 3 factor(bminewcat)2 1.38       0.0690       4.71 2.47e-  6 1.21      1.58    
 4 factor(bminewcat)3 1.39       0.0783       4.16 3.18e-  5 1.19      1.61    
 5 n_rels             1.58       0.0705       6.50 8.27e- 11 1.37      1.81    
 6 factor(race_eth)2  0.745      0.146       -2.02 4.34e-  2 0.554     0.980   
 7 factor(race_eth)3  0.459      0.190       -4.09 4.26e-  5 0.309     0.654   
 8 factor(race_eth)4  0.830      0.144       -1.29 1.98e-  1 0.618     1.09    
 9 factor(race_eth)9  0.756      0.240       -1.16 2.45e-  1 0.455     1.17    
10 factor(meno)1      2.83       0.294        3.54 3.93e-  4 1.62      5.12    
11 bdnewcat           2.71       0.146        6.81 9.79e- 12 2.05      3.64    
12 biopsycoll         1.63       0.0790       6.20 5.63e- 10 1.40      1.90    
13 birads             1.47       0.0677       5.68 1.31e-  8 1.29      1.68    
14 bdnewcat:meno      0.594      0.159       -3.29 1.02e-  3 0.432     0.805   

As you can see, the OR for 'meno' increases in R. I'm stumped as to why. I'd really like to figure out what's causing this and what's the correct set of results to use.
My data is more than 70,000 observations; I am not familiar with how to provide a data example but if someone could provide guidance on this as well I would be grateful.
Things I've already tried:

Inputting 'meno' into the R model as both a non-factor and a factor - same issue persists.
Making sure the same dataset has been imported into both software systems.
Running the model in both softwares without the interaction term. Mysteriously, the results end up identical; could this be a difference in the two systems in how interactions are handled?


Hi welcome to stackoverflow! Here is how to make a great reprex. Honestly, my guess is the difference is likely due to stata and R having different reference categories

The coefficients for meno in the R and Stata outputs are reciprocals of each other. Does that give you a clue?

Honestly it’s kind of hard to tell with the data! If you do dput(train data) we could reproduce the result and figure out what could be going on!

Hi @JoshAllen, I ended up finding a solution to my problem thanks to another commenter! Turns out the issue was that I needed to enter the variables as factors in both the main effects and the interaction. I will take your suggestion to use reprex for future questions - thanks so much.

@tomatosauce Awesome!

In Stata, variables meno and bdnewcat were treated as factor (categorical) variables in main effect and the interaction terms. In R, you treated the variable bdnewcat as a numeric (or continuous) variable in main effect and interaction terms. It is likely that the variable bdnewcat is currently defined as numeric in R instead of factor in the data frame.
I would try to explicitly define bdnewcat and meno as factor in logistic model:
trainmodel <- glm(
  sfcancer2yr ~ age + factor(bminewcat) + n_rels + factor(race_eth) + 
    factor(meno) + factor(bdnewcat) + biopsycoll + birads + 
    factor(bdnewcat):factor(meno),
  family = "binomial"(link = "logit"),
  data = traindata
)

Please check if it makes any difference as I can't check it without the data.

Hi Zhiqiang, your solution worked! My R results now match my Stata results. Seems obvious to treat the variables the same in the interaction as they are in the main effects but somehow didn't occur to me. Thank you so much!
